# Different definition of $K_0(R)$. Prove equivalence

Tags: commutative-algebra, projective-module, algebraic-k-theory

I need to prove that the following two definitions of the zero-th $K$-theory group of a ring $R$ (with unit) are equivalent.

> **def 1** the abelian group generated by the isomorphism classes $[P]$ of $R$-projective modules (finitely generated) under the identification $[P\oplus Q]=[P]+[Q]$
>
> **def2** The Grothendieck group of the monoid of isomorphism classes of finitely generated $R$-proj. module, with operation the direct sum.

**My attempt** Call $K^1$ the abelian group with the first def, and $K^2$ the group with the second one.  I defined a map $K^1 \to K^2$ as $$\lambda[P] \mapsto (\oplus_{\lambda}[P],0)$$ and $$-\lambda[Q] \mapsto (0,\oplus_{\lambda}[Q])$$ for $\lambda$ positive integer. Now the map is clearly surjective and well-defined. But I don't know how to prove **injectiviness**. I mean, should be fairly easy but I got stuck in th following step: for simplicity assume that $[P]-[Q] \mapsto ([P],[Q])\sim (0,0)$. By definition of Grothendieck group there exists a finely generated proj module $C$ such that $P\oplus C \simeq Q \oplus C$. But now I don't know how to get rid of such $C$ in order to prove that $0=[P]-[Q]$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P \oplus C \cong Q \oplus C$, then $[P \oplus C] = [Q \oplus C]$ in $K^1$, hence $[P] + [C] = [Q] + [C]$ in $K^1$, hence $[P] - [Q] = 0$ in $K^1$.

Comment: argh. Why everything is so easy and clear when someone else explains to you? Thanks!! :)

Comment: @Luigi: to me, conceptually the point is that both of the abelian groups you describe have the same universal property: they are the universal map from isomorphism classes of objects in $C$ (here the category of f.g.p. modules) to an abelian group sending direct sums to the group operation.